# PHP Fatal error: bytes exhausted Após executar query laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query, memória

Olá, em um determinado processo do meu código eu preciso executar um query que me retorna 4500 linhas do banco de dados

```
 return Property::whereHas('portals', function ($query) {
        $query->where('portal_id', '=', '1');
    })->get();
```

Após executar essa query eu faço uma verificação em cada linha.

O problema é que antes de fazer a verificação o php acusa um erro de memoria 
`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted`

Em ambiente local eu troquei o memory_limit no php.ini para 512M e a função rodou OK. O problema é que isso não é uma solução pra mim, que vou rodar isso em servidor online.

Eu preciso dividir esse resultado antes de executar a verificação, mas não sei como, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Colocou o limite na query? Fazer uma query sem limite é algo inviável, seria melhor implementar paginação.

Comment: Como faço para implementar a paginação? Não posso por um limite na query porque eu posso ter um numero infinito de Properties

Comment: Ivan estou tetando aqui, mas acho que terá que usar `::has`, todavia vou ler a documentação e falar com um colega, pois eu realmente não entendo de Eloquent (é que uso outro framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende da versão do seu laravel, em versões mais antigas você pode usar:

```
 return Property::whereHas('portals', function ($query) {
    $query->where('portal_id', '=', '1');
})->take(10)->skip(10)->get();
```

Que pegaria (TAKE) 10 resultados após pular (SKIP) os 10 primeiros;

Em versões mais recentes o código seria:

```
return Property::whereHas('portals', function ($query) {
    $query->where('portal_id', '=', '1');
})->limit(10)->offset(10)->get();
```

Então para paginar seu resultado você somente alteraria o OFFSET ou o SKIP.

Comment: minha função ficou assim:                                                                 public function get($skip, $limit)
    {
        $propertyList = Property::whereHas('portals', function ($query) {
            $query->where('portal_id', '=', '1');
        })->limit($limit)->skip($skip)->get();
} o problema, é em como saber em quantos eu tenho que dar skip toda vez que eu executar essa função

Comment: Faça um contador, com uma variavel qualquer $skipped = 0; toda vez que você chamar esta sua função você faz $skipped += $skip, onde $skip foi o valor "pulado". Lembre que sua funcao get($skip, $limit) deve receber o $skipped no lugar do $skip.

Comment: O contador no meu caso não ajudou ficou for($skiped = 0 ; $skiped < = count($properties) ; $skiped += count($p)){ $this->get($skiped, count($properties)); }

Comment: Fiz um exemplo para ilustrar meu raciocinio: http://paste.ofcode.org/35jTyH6csvu5Zhx3j3kvrPa

Comment: Eu não entendi direito como que eu vou aplicar esse seu raciocínio no meu caso já que eu tenho que fazer varias verificações e mandar pra uma fila.http://paste.ofcode.org/ReZsTq3PxS8bKXqNSGnApk

Comment: Olha se facilita: http://paste.ofcode.org/YAHx5QK7UdcL7KDgTfPZ5m

Comment: Ficou assim http://paste.ofcode.org/3b3spfNSkLeGsQ3qW7pD8Cf  está certo?

Comment: Com essa parte do codigo que voce esta passando nao consigo saber o que falta, mas como esta nao funciona, comentei: http://paste.ofcode.org/xe2pqGKR6xPSdNdFeTQNtk

Comment: Tem razão, eu testei aqui e não funcionou, eu fiz umas alterações http://paste.ofcode.org/JUjpj2Aue5EfvATibPdTfV

Comment: Acredito que esteja claro: http://paste.ofcode.org/3afx8PxdQGHck3xhh2kxpV

Comment: Agora entendi, valeu!